# curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:

Tags: curl

First I can't use `-k/--insecure`, if I do so the server won't respond at all.

If I try `curl https://10.10.10.127/ --cacert ./Cert.p12` || `curl https://10.10.10.127/ --cacert /etc/ssl/certsCert.p12`, It throws me below error:

> curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
>    CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/Cert.p12
>    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

So I read some threads about why this happen and it's probably because `curl` is expecting the certificate to be at `/etc/ssl/certs` so I copied it to that directory and set the certificate permission to `777`, and retried but still got the same error. I also tried to put `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/cert` that didn't work as well, even I execute the command from the terminal. I also tried `apt-get install ca-certificates` which I had the latest version installed, so that didn't fix the issue too.
I also converted the certificate in `.crt` format but still having the issue.

Is there something I am missing? or if possible can I import my certificate to w3m browser terminal?